# How to speed up data transfer while capturing rejected rows from tMySqlOutput?

Tags: mysql, talend

I am transferring data from table in one schema to the table in another schema. I also need to record rows that get rejected in the process, due to one of the many reasons, for example, constraint of NOT NULL failing.

When I attach the reject link with the output component, the transfer speed decreases drastically to 2-3 rows per second. On the other hand, without reject link, I can use "Extend Insert" option and the speed increases to 400 rows per second.

How can I capture rejected rows without compromising on the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the methodology suggested above by **@Corentin** . I came up with an effective solution for my problem using the same idea. Instead of letting DB return with an error for each row in case of breaking of constraint, I am checking for rejection within the Talend, using the component **tSchemaComplianceCheck**, which contains schema exactly the same as the destination table & carrying out rejection link from this component.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is no perfect choice : in your case I think the best thing to do is trying to catch null fields before inserting , with a tMap placed before tDBOutput : there you can have a filter on your output ("row.field1 is not null") , and a second output dedicated to output rejects. This way you can get your rejected data, and still be using the extended insert for better performances.